Need to have a Pandas Dataframe df.describe() outputted such that column are named by a concat of statistic and col name thus 1 header and 1 data row
Searched high and low to no avail. I have a Pandas dataframe describe() with say 3 columns named Height, Weigh, Mass and to keep it short a list of statistics like mean, std, min, max generated by describe(). Note this dataframe is created by the contents of one of perhaps 1000 files of the same type of data and each file has anywhere up to about 50 to 200 or more rows of data with 13 columns of which in this example i am only showing 3 columns.
I need to transform that array of x rows of stats for my various y columns into a dataframe of one row of data and one row for header.
eg.
          Height     Weight     Mass
Mean      5          8          12
std       2          1          3
min       3          5          6
max       7          10         13.5

want my output to be like the following
Height-mean Height-std Height-min Height-max Weight-mean Weight-std Weight-min Weight-max..... .......on to the 3rd column
5            2           3           7           8            1           5           10 ......

so essentially a concatenation of the header and rows(stat labels) ... Ultimately I want to output this 2 row table or at least the data row to a csv and run through all the files (see above up to around 1000 and append their data to the csv and then import that file so i can find the file(s) with the optimal values for my various columns.  Perhaps I am way out to lunch and not grasping how to perform this requirement and going about it totally wrong but I thought this would be possible with python.
I have tried searching for a few hours here on this site and others around python packages but seems like pandas should be able to do it but even when I think i have someone asking a similar question it just doesnt seem like it gets answered correctly. Thank you for any of your expertise in this matter

Use DataFrame.unstack with convert to DataFrame by Series.to_frame and transpose by DataFrame.T, last flatten MultiIndex:
out = df.unstack().to_frame().T
out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}')
print (out)
   Height-Mean  Height-std  Height-min  Height-max  Weight-Mean  Weight-std  \
0          5.0         2.0         3.0         7.0          8.0         1.0   

   Weight-min  Weight-max  Mass-Mean  Mass-std  Mass-min  Mass-max  
0         5.0        10.0       12.0       3.0       6.0      13.5  

Another idea is use DataFrame constructor with MultiIndex.from_product and flatten values by numpy.ravel:
cols = [f'{x[0]}-{x[1]}' for x in pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.index])]
out = pd.DataFrame([df.to_numpy().ravel('F')], columns=cols)
print (out)
   Height-Mean  Height-std  Height-min  Height-max  Weight-Mean  Weight-std  \
0          5.0         2.0         3.0         7.0          8.0         1.0   

   Weight-min  Weight-max  Mass-Mean  Mass-std  Mass-min  Mass-max  
0         5.0        10.0       12.0       3.0       6.0      13.5  


OMG  working off your 1st solution i changed to out = df.describe().unstack().to_frame().T       it appears to have worked with the properties of the describe output ... Very impressed.  I have a lot to learn and I must thank you profusely. Cheers and all the best to you.

Try the following code
result = {}
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    result.update({col+"-"+i:val for col, val in row.to_dict().items()})
pd.DataFrame(result, index=[0])


Thank you Mohit for your response.  It was much appreciated. however please see first answer and that had solved the question.
